# running jersy showing 404

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

Hi I'm using simple web application using. I'm new to it and just set the environment using the tutorials found in the web .

These are the JARS I have added to make run jersey

[image: Jersey Jars]

and my project structure

[image: project structure]

so while running tomcat doesn't show any error in console but when I access using the url

```
http://localhost:8080/restwebservice/solomon/restapi
```

I'm getting 404 resource not found error. And this is my code

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/restapi")
public class RestHelloworld {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String textRequest(){
        return "Hello there thanks for contacting plain text";
    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String xmlRequest(){
        return " <?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<contacttype> xml bitch </contacttype>";               }


}
```

These are all i have. Still I can't understand where the problem lies. Please help me so that I can proceed.

Comment: you need to provide more information. what does your console show when you  start the server? your `web.xml` file? are you getting the tomcat homepage when you hit `http://localhost:8080`?

Comment: no didnt get tomcat home page

Comment: Then the setup is not proper. you need to first make sure that `http://localhost:8080/` gives you the tomcat homepage.

Comment: after setting up tomcat properly now getting tomcat home page but while accesing url via rest client getting request resource is not available

Comment: Have you heard of maven? These dependency problems will go away...

Answer (score 0):

after changing this configuration
double click on the server tab -> select server locations ->use tomcat installation

worked fine thanks for the answers guys